# Javascript async/await question : Unable to fiqure about why the program is not returning any error

Tags: javascript, async-await, assert, assertion

Refer to the function

```
async function dq(isOk){
if(isOk) {return "OK";}
else {throw new Error("not OK");}
}
```

What assertion accurately tests above code:

1. console.assert(await dq(true),'OK');
2. console.assert(await(dq(true),'not OK'));
3. console.assert(await dq(true),'not OK');
4. console.assert(dq(true),'OK');

for the all the 4 options I get undefined in dev console even for option 2 where await() is never a function.

Comment: try to use it inside an async function `(async () => {
console.assert((await dq(true)));
})()`

Answer (score 0):

If a promise resolves normally, then await promise returns the result. But in the case of a rejection, it throws the error, just as if there were a throw statement at that line.

```
async function f() {
  await Promise.reject(new Error("Whoops!"));
}
```

In real situations, the promise may take some time before it rejects. In that case there will be a delay before await throws an error.
We can catch that error using try..catch, the same way as a regular throw:

```
async function f() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://no-such-url');
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
  }
}
f();
```

If we forget to add .catch there, then we get an unhandled promise error (viewable in the console). We can catch such errors using a global unhandledrejection event handler.

Reference https://javascript.info/async-await.

Comment: Hi Ankkit, 

Thanks for the message, I understood your point but the above async method dq do not have promise associated inside it so in that case I was checking the behaviour. I can assure 4th option is incorrect as it will fire before async function dq